# how to post variables to php using Flash Form?

Tags: php, flash, forms

I am using this code. The input text fields names are Name and Home.

```
on (release) {
    getURL("test.php", "", "POST");
}
```

And the test file is

```
<?PHP

$a=$_POST['Name'];
$b=$_POST['Home'];`

echo "$a";
echo "$b";

?>
```

But it is showing the variables values in URL bar.

Answer (score 1):

There is error on your code. Don't include the variables inside quotes. Try this code instead.

```
<?php

$a=$_POST['Name'];
$b=$_POST['Home'];

echo $a;
echo $b;

?>
```

[or]

Use the LoadVariables function instead of getURL
Check the link here.
http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/flash_php_email.htm

Comment: still showing variables value in the URL bar
like this 
http://localhost/xampp/test.php?Name=1&Home=2
I enter 1 in the Name field and 2 in the Home Field